# How can get monthly spend of an ads account using bing ads api with soap api method

Tags: bing, bing-api, bing-ads-api

This is Example api call which return campaigns data in response, I need to get last30_days spend of a campaigns.

```
    <s:Envelope xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Header xmlns="https://bingads.microsoft.com/CampaignManagement/v13">
    <Action mustUnderstand="1">GetCampaignsByAccountId</Action>
    <AuthenticationToken i:nil="false">access token</AuthenticationToken>
    <CustomerAccountId i:nil="false">acc_id</CustomerAccountId>
    <CustomerId i:nil="false">cus_id</CustomerId>
    <DeveloperToken i:nil="false">dev_token</DeveloperToken>
  </s:Header>
  <s:Body>
    <GetCampaignsByAccountIdRequest xmlns="https://bingads.microsoft.com/CampaignManagement/v13">
      <AccountId>acc_id</AccountId>
      <CampaignType>Search</CampaignType>
    </GetCampaignsByAccountIdRequest>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```